# how do i change the applicationId dynamically for chromecast android

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, castcompanionlibrary

I want to change the applicationId, for the baseCastManager after it's been initialized?

Is there a preferred way to do this? mApplicationId.

@alinaddaff where are you :)

I was just going to use a setApplicationId(String applicationid) method on an inherited CastManager.

Comment: Changing application id dynamically is not currently supported. Can you elaborate what you are trying to do?

Comment: we want to be able to switch the chomecast receiver app server side.  The client app is driven by an api that supplies the chomecast app id to the client.

Comment: But can it be done by not initializing cast first till you get the right app id from your server first and then initialize CCL? Or do you need to have one app id to begin with and then later change it again?

Comment: one app to begin with and change it when I get the response from the server.  Looks like it is working, but just wanted to know if there were any bad side effects from doing it. The app won't get past the splash screen until it gets a valid chromecast id from the server

Comment: Why don't you delay the cast initialization till the server sends the right one?

Comment: I had done that initially but it looked like the CCL was trying to connect to some services and broadcast receivers which threw some handleReceiver or handleCreateService errors. I can take a look again.  Thanks Ali